# Cat a file(raw) to UDP at specific bitrate

Tags: udp, cat

I'm looking for a way to transfer a file over UDP at an specific bitrate. I can use `netcat` for example like this:

```
cat file | nc -u 192.168.x.x 5000
```

And I use a custom application to listen at port 5000 at client side.

Is there any way to "cat a file raw to udp" at a specific bitrate?

Comment: Do you want a min or max bitrate when writing that file?

Answer (score 8):

PV (Pipe Viewer) [has the ability](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/quickref/pv.shtml) to rate-limit a pipe.

pv -L 512k

> -L RATE, --rate-limit RATE Limit the transfer to a maximum of RATE
>   bytes per second. A suffix of "k", "m", "g", or "t" can be added to
>   denote kilobytes (*1024), megabytes, and so on.

You can either [install it from source from here](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) or install it with a package manager for your distribution.

So you'd do:

```
cat file | pv -L 512k | nc -u 192.168.x.x 5000
```